# How do I get the background images to transition in less time like on the flickr homepage so they show for 5 seconds and take .4s to transition?

Tags: html, css, animation, frontend

In trying to clone the flickr homepage I've become stuck trying to get the background images to transition just as they do on the [flickr homepage](https://flickr.com).

I tried using keyframes instead of javascript and the transition-duration and animation-duration properties.

the following is a distillation of the problem in code.

html document

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>flickr_test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

css document

```
body {
    background-color: rgb(61, 61, 61);
    background-image: url(./test_images/computers.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    animation: changePhoto 100s ease-in-out forwards infinite;
    
}

@keyframes changePhoto {
    0% {
        background-image: url(./test_images/engineer.jpg);
    }
    10% {
        background-image: url(./test_images/lion.jpg);
    }
    20% {
        background-image: url(./test_images/horse.jpg);
    }
    30% {
        background-image: url(./test_images/mountains.jpg);
    }
    40% {
        background-image: url(./test_images/forest.jpg);
    }
    50% {
        background-image: url(./test_images/computers.jpg);
    }
    60% {
        background-image: url(./test_images/northernLights.jpg);
    }
    70% {
        background-image: url(./test_images/stars.jpg);
    }
    80% {
        background-image: url(./test_images/fern.jpg);
    }
    90% {
        background-image: url(./test_images/fish.jpg);
    }
    100% {
        background-image: url(./test_images/meditation.jpg);
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe this needs to be done using javascript. preferably a library for slider, or use this approach with opacity [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73144463/3807365)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use js to make smother transitions by adding

```
body {
transition: all ease .4s 
}
```

or

```
 body {
    transition: all ease 5s 
    }
```

that could works for what you want, so for experience I highly suggest you to use JS

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with pure CSS - but the keyframes will change if the number of images changes so for a real situation you may want to use some JS to calculate the %s required in the keyframes

This simple snippet though just takes your layout of 10 images and says let's have the whole thing lasting for 50seconds - each image taking a percentage of their alloted 5 seconds to go from opacity 0 to opacity 1 and the same percentage to go from opacity 1 to opacity 0

We need an interlacing of the images coming and going and you can't do that on all common browsers with just one set of keyframes because some browsers don't try to animate the opacity of changing backgrounds (I found Chrome does but Firefox doesn't).

Therefore we put half the images into keyframes changing the background of the body's before pseudo element, and the other half onto the after pseudo element. And we offset the start (so it starts part way through) of one set so as to get the overlapping.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>flickr_test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
  <style>
    @keyframes changePhoto1 {
      0% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/400/300);
        opacity: 0;
      }
      1%,
      9% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/400/300);
        opacity: 1;
      }
      10% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/400/300);
        opacity: 0;
      }
      19% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/12/400/300);
        opacity: 0;
      }
      20%,
      29% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/12/400/300);
        opacity: 1;
      }
      30% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/12/400/300);
        opacity: 0;
      }
      39% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/14/400/300);
        opacity: 0;
      }
      40%,
      49% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/14/400/300);
        opacity: 1;
      }
      50% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/14/400/300);
        opacity: 0;
      }
      59% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/16/400/300);
        opacity: 0;
      }
      60%,
      69% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/16/400/300);
        opacity: 1;
      }
      70% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/16/400/300);
        opacity: 0;
      }
      79% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/18/400/300);
        opacity: 0;
      }
      80%,
      89% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/18/400/300);
        opacity: 1;
      }
      90% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/18/400/300);
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/400/300);
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes changePhoto2 {
      0% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/11/400/300);
        opacity: 0;
      }
      1%,
      9% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/11/400/300);
        opacity: 1;
      }
      10% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/11/400/300);
        opacity: 0;
      }
      19% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/13/400/300);
        opacity: 0;
      }
      20%,
      29% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/13/400/300);
        opacity: 1;
      }
      30% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/13/400/300);
        opacity: 0;
      }
      39% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/15/400/300);
        opacity: 0;
      }
      40%,
      49% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/15/400/300);
        opacity: 1;
      }
      50% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/15/400/300);
        opacity: 0;
      }
      59% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/17/400/300);
        opacity: 0;
      }
      60%,
      69% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/17/400/300);
        opacity: 1;
      }
      70% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/17/400/300);
        opacity: 0;
      }
      79% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/19/400/300);
        opacity: 0;
      }
      80%,
      89% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/19/400/300);
        opacity: 1;
      }
      90% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/19/400/300);
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/11/400/300);
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
    
    body {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/11/400/300);
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    body::after,
    body::before {
      content: '';
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: rgb(61, 61, 61);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      rbackground-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
      animation: changePhoto1 50s linear forwards infinite;
      position: fixed;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    body::after {
      animation: changePhoto2 50s linear forwards infinite;
      animation-delay: -5s;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>

</html>
```